# WP SMTP Plugin is not reading wp-config constant variables

Tags: php, wordpress, smtp

For transactional emails in WordPress, I am using WP Mail SMTP plugin and defining Email Authentication constants in wp-config.php file to add Third party Email services configurations.

**Problem:**
I have mentioned all the configurations in the wp-config file and below is the screenshot. This is working perfectly fine on another website on the same host and sending all the emails.

[Wp Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HODh1.png)

[WP SMTP Mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NwNb.png)

On the above **WP SMTP**, you can see that the plugin **configuration setting page** is not reading those wp-config files constants that I defined.

I am looking for the problem that I could not figure out yet, anyone who has gone through the same issue, Please help me solve it?

Comment: you can try to use Easy WP Mail Plugin and set up the SMTP configuration's details in your project. Finally, test it

Comment: Does Easy WP Mail Plugin give the option to add constants in wp-config file? if so how is the constants defined?

Comment: yes, there is given the option on backend admin. So, you can configure the details on admin.

Comment: @PriyankaModi Please check my thread again, I asked for wp-config constants option and this is our requirements. We are not looking for plugins configurations through their setting page.

Answer (score 0):

It could be server side issue or some of the other plugins or theme's script conflicting with WP Mail SMTP plugin. Also, make sure which PHP version is installed on your server.